# jQuery accordion - changing behaviour of on click event

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, accordion

I'm using an accordion to essentially display a list of chapters that are in a book.  Currently the user needs to click on the title, the accordion then drops down to display a brief few words 'and' a link that takes them to the actual pdf document.  This works fine but I've been asked if the contents header of the accordion could open directly removing the need for the drop down and additional clicking of the link.

I've not dealt a lot of accordions and am a bit of a query noob, is this doable at all?  The css is targeting the same elements and all attempts have so far failed.

I've added the code below that generates the accordion which may help.  If I could remove the drop down effect from item[0] (the contents), I'd be making good progress :)

Thanks for any help.

```
<div id="accordion">
    <?php
    $description = array(
        "Contents",
        "Introduction",
        "Lifecycle",
        "Data Management",
        "Assurance",
        "Pressure Management",
        "Abandonment");
    $title = array(
        "Contents",
        "Introduction",
        "Lifecycle",
        "Well Integrity Assurance",
        "Assurance",
        "Annular Pressure Management",
        "Abandonment",
        "appendicies");
    $contents = <<<EOT
            <h3><a href="#">$title[0] </a></h3>
            <div class=trainingItemListContainer>
                <div class="subDetails">
                    <div class="viewAndDownload">
                        <a href="training_chap01.php"><p>View Contents</p></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h3><a href="#">Chapter 01 - $title[1] </a></h3>
            <div class=trainingItemListContainer>
                <div class="subDetails">
                    <div class="viewAndDownload">
                        <a href="training_chap02.php"><p>View Contents</p></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
EOT;
    echo $contents;
    for($i=2; $i <= 6; $i++){
        $number = str_pad((($i-1 ) + 1), 2, "00", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $number2 = str_pad(($i  + 1), 2, "00", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $body = <<<EOT
            <h3><a href="#">Chapter $number - $title[$i] </a></h3>
            <div class=trainingItemListContainer>
                <div class="subDetails">
                    <div class="viewAndDownload">
                        <a href="training_chap$number2.php"><p>View chapter</p></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

EOT;
    echo $body;
    }
            $appendicies = <<<EOT
            <h3><a href="#">Appendix 4 - Worked Example, Derivation of MAASP</a></h3>
            <div class=trainingItemListContainer>
                <div class="subDetails">
                    <div class="viewAndDownload">
                       <a href="training_chap08_app3.php"><p>View appendix details</p></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
EOT;
    echo $appendicies
    ?>

    <!--end accordion div--> </div>
```

Comment: correct me i am wrong .. you want to pre-open the accordion ...

Comment: @Runcorn - :) What I'd like is for the very first element to not have the accordion affect when clicked, I'd like it to go straight to the page instead whilst maintaining the same aesthetics as the rest of the page.

Comment: Please create a fiddle of your code, so that it will give a clear idea to us.